# Hair dynamics sends particles flying when mesh moves

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to use dynamic hair for an animation, but every time I turn it on, the hair warps, then "explodes" when the mesh is moved. It doesn't get any better when I try to bake the dynamics into the system. I'm completely at a loss as to what could be the cause. Any and all help will be much appreciated. I've attached the .blend file, in case anyone wanted to tinker with it.

Edit: I've updated the blend file to better showcase the problem, as I've removed the armature entirely, and the problem is still there.

[image]
[image: Hair Particles seem to explode when dynamics are enabled.]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the armature is above the particle system in the modifier panel
And go back to the frame where you begin caching
Or bake the hair dynamics

Comment: It is. Could the weights somehow be affecting the hair?

Comment: Make sure the armature is above the particle system in the modifier panel

Comment: It is above the amature, but the thing is, when I completely removed the armature, vertex groups, etc, I had the exact same problem. One thing that did fix the problem was completely removing and re-adding a new hair particle system, but it took me about a week to make that fur, so I'd really hate to lose all of that work.

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is an old post. but what i did to fix this problem was,

1. Duplicate the particle system causing the issue
2. Disable or delete original(weight map should still be applied from duplicating.)

and my problem was fixed.